# What is this type of AC power connector called?

Tags: power, connector

What is the name of this style connection?

<strike>It seems to be more popular with electrical powered equipment for the Asian market.</strike>

[image]

Comment: My HP Elite Book charger had the same plug from 2010... So it is not just Asian.

Comment: Its the same as the figure 8 connector, but grounded. International.

Comment: It is not "the same as the figure 8 connector".  The C7/C8 connector is NOT interchangable with the C6/C6 connector unless you do substantial plastic surgery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IEC 60320 female type "C5" and male type "C6"
aka. "Mickey Mouse" or "cloverleaf"

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C5.2FC6_coupler

Answer (score 4):

Apparently it is an [IEC 60320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) type connector and is a [C5 or C6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C5.2FC6_coupler) depending on if its the plug or socket.